# setup:di:compile ignores third party type definition (Monolog)

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, di, setup-di-compile, 3rd-party-library

I have a DI configuration for a custom exception handler:

```
<type name="My\Logger\Handler\ExceptionHandler">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="formatter" xsi:type="object">My\Logger\Formatter\LogstashFormatterVirtual</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<type name="Monolog\Formatter\LogstashFormatter">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="applicationName" xsi:type="string">Magento</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

This works fine in developer mode, but if I run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`, I get the following error as soon as the exception handler would be instantiated:

```
Missing required argument $applicationName of Monolog\Formatter\LogstashFormatter.
```

How can I ensure that compilation includes the Monolog type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I still do not understand why it does not work, I solved it by using a virtual type instead:

```
<type name="My\Logger\Handler\ExceptionHandler">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="formatter" xsi:type="object">My\Logger\Formatter\LogstashFormatterVirtual</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<virtualType name="My\Logger\Formatter\LogstashFormatterVirtual" type="Monolog\Formatter\LogstashFormatter">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="applicationName" xsi:type="string">Magento</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try **virtual type** instead of **type** in your XML file.

Comment: that's what I figured out just now as well :D thank you!

Comment: @FabianSchmengler Great ! You are welcome.